# How to avoid Master Browser errors, MRxSmb Event ID 8003?

Tags: active-directory, windows-event-log, windows-sbs-2003

I have a domain with *Windows SBS 2003* as domain controller. It's very common to get Master Browser errors in the logs, MRxSmb Event ID 8003. How can I avoid that? What have I done wrong?

I know how to solve this: Stop the `Computer Browser` service on clients, but I don't know how to avoid this since the problem comes back every time I add a new client and I forget to stop the `Computer Browser` service.

Error message:

```
The master browser has received a server announcement from the computer
[computer] that believes that it is the master browser for the domain on
transport NetBT_Tcpip_{#######-####-####-#. The master browser is stopping 
or an election is being forced.
```

Is there an configuration of the server to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any legacy boxes on your network you can just disable the browser service entirely in a top-level Domain GPO: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256345

Comment: Thanks, that is a solution! But I would like to know what misconfiguration of the server that causes these messages.

Comment: No misconfiguration really, it's not actually an error on your setup, and is only relevant if you're using WINS/NetBIOS on your network.

Comment: Your link points to "How To Configure Group Policies to Set Security for System Services" -- I can't see how that helps in this situation. I assume you meant to provide a link describing how to "disable the browser service entirely"?

Comment: @Styne666 - nitpicking a 7.5 year old answer! Anyway, you should probably read step 14 of the procedure outlined in the link.

Comment: No, it wasn't a nitpick. It was a genuine question about how the link was relevant. I assume what you're saying is create a GPO with a service in `Computer Configuration, Preferences, Control Panel Settings, Services` for `Service name: Browser`, `Startup: Disabled`, `Service Action: Stop service`.

Comment: @Styne666 - context. Group policy, *as it was at the time this question was asked*, and bearing in mind that the question is about SBS *2003*, didn't have preferences and this was how you would set a service to disabled.